# angular ui-router can't find script template in head

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to inject a inline template into my body but I'm getting a

`GET http://localhost:3000/home.html 404 (Not Found)` error in the console.

I've included the script in the head.

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title Movieseat

    %script{:id => "/home.html", :type => "text/ng-template"}
      .page-header
        %h1 Flapper News

  %body{"ng-app" => "movieseat"}

    %div{"ui-view" => ""}
    %a{"ui-sref" => "state1"} State 1
    %a{"ui-sref" => "state2"} State 2
    %a{"ui-sref" => "home"} home
```

And this is the route module,

```
angular.module('movieseat').config([

  '$urlRouterProvider', '$stateProvider', function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider

    .state('home', {
      url: '/home',
      templateUrl: '/home.html',
      controller: 'searchCtrl'
    })

    .state('state1', {
      url: '/state1',
      templateUrl: 'assets/angular-app/templates/state1.html'
    })

    .state('state2', {
      url: "/state2",
      templateUrl: "assets/angular-app/templates/state2.html"
    })
  }

]);
```

Is there something wrong with the html > erb conversion on the script tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After very carefully reading I saw I needed to put the script inside the body, and not in the head. After putting it in the footer, with the rest of the scripts it works.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `ng-app` is on `body` so the script tag in head is outside of the scope of your main angular module.

If templateUrl doesn't exist in $templateCache or in script tag ( also ends up in $templateCache), a request is made to server to retrieve it.

Since your tag is outside scope of the app it is not found and therefore generates the server request.

Possible solutions:

Move script tag inside body or move `ng-app` attribute to `<html>` tag